# gotoxy prints wrong in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, switch-statement

I am making a menu for a store with 4 options; add product, delete product, see table of created products and exit the program.
I finished the option to add products and exit, they both work fine.

Now I have to make the option to see the product table, supposedly I had already finished it but I noticed a problem ...

The first time I go in to see the product table, it prints it to me normally, like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zDkT.png)

But when I go to the menu and go back to the product table, it prints it like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C05Pz.png)

Like I said, it only prints it right the first time I see it, then it prints it wrong.
Do you know how I can solve it?

This is the part of the code where I print the product table.

```
void table()
{
    int c = k, m = 7;
    system("cls");
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Table of created products";
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << " number of order ";
    cout << "|     Name of product      |";
    cout << "   Product code    |";
    cout << "  Amount  |";
    cout << "   Unit price   |";
    cout << " Subtotal |";
    cout << "    IVA    |";
    cout << " total price |";
    cout << endl;
    cout << "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------";
    cout << endl;
    for (int L = 2; L <= c; L++)
    {
        cout << "                 ";
        cout << "|                          |";
        cout << "                   |";
        cout << "          |";
        cout << "                |";
        cout << "          |";
        cout << "           |";
        cout << "             |";
        cout << endl;
        cout << "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------";
        cout << endl;

    }

    for (int h = 1; h < c; h++)
    {

        gotoxy(8, m);
        cout << product[h].numor;
        gotoxy(20, m);
        cout << product[h].descr;
        gotoxy(52, m);
        cout << product[h].cod;
        gotoxy(70, m);
        cout << product[h].cant;
        gotoxy(83, m);
        cout << "$" << product[h].preuni;
        gotoxy(96, m);
        cout << "$" << product[h].subt;
        gotoxy(107, m);
        cout << "$" << product[h].IVA;
        gotoxy(119, m);
        cout << "$" << product[h].total;
        m = m + 4;
    }
    cout << "\n\n\n";
    system("pause");
    system("cls");
}
```

This is my complete code (maybe I have one or another library too many because I have been experimenting).

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string>
#include<ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <windows.h>  
#include<iomanip>

using namespace std;

struct products
{
    int numor{},
        cant{};
    float preuni{},
        subt{},
        IVA{},
        total{};
    string cod{};
    string descr{};
}product[51];

void add();
void intro_code();
int val_code(char codigo[]);
void table();
void gotoxy(int x, int y);

int i = 1;                //Product No. (counter)
int k = 1;  //Consecutive number (counter)


int main()
{
    char opc;

    cout << "                Welcome ";
    cout << endl;


    cout << "\n1.- Add product.";
    cout << "\n2.- Delete product.";
    cout << "\n3.- Table of created products.";
    cout << "\n4.- Exit";
    cout << endl;
    cout << "\nWhat do you want to do today?: "; cin >> opc;




    switch (opc)
    {
    case '1':
        system("cls");
        cout << "\nAdd product";
        add();
        system("pause");
        system("cls");
        return main();
    case '2':
        cout << "\nDelete product";
        system("cls");
        return main();
    case '3':
        table();
        return main();
    case '4':
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    default:
        system("cls");
        cout << "Warning: the data entered is not correct, try again.\n\n";
        return main();
    }
    return 0;
}

void add()
{
    int can;

    cout << "\nHow many products do you want to register?: "; cin >> can;

    if (can <= 0 || can > 51)
    {
        system("cls");
        cout << "Warning: The amount of products entered is not valid, try again";
        return add();


    }

    for (int p = 1; p <= can;)
    {
        if (i < 51)
        {
            if (k <= 51)        // In this part, consecutive numbers are generated automatically
            {
                cout << "\nNumber of order: ";
                cout << k;
                cout << endl;
                product[i].numor = k;
                k++;
            }
            cin.ignore();
            cout << "Name of product: ";
            getline(cin, product[i].descr);
            intro_code();
            cout << "Quantity to sell: "; cin >> product[i].cant;
            cout << "unit price: $"; cin >> product[i].preuni;
            product[i].subt = product[i].preuni * product[i].cant;
            cout << "Subtotal: $" << product[i].subt;
            product[i].IVA = product[i].subt * 0.16;
            cout << "\nIVA: $" << product[i].IVA;
            product[i].total = product[i].subt + product[i].IVA;
            cout << "\nTotal price: $" << product[i].total;
            cout << "\n-------------------------------------------------------------------------------";
            cout << endl;
            i++;
        }
        p++;
    }
}
/*In this function the product code is entered, if the user enters a code
less than or greater than 5 characters the program displays an error message and allows the
user try again.*/
void intro_code()
{
    char hello[10];
    int xyz;
    do {
        cout << "Code of product (5 digits): ";
        cin.getline(hello, 10, '\n');
        if (strlen(hello) != 5)
        {
            cout << "The data entered is incorrect, try again ...";
            cout << endl;
            return intro_code();
        }
        else
        {
            xyz = val_code(hello);
        }
    } while (xyz == 0);
    product[i].cod = hello;
}
/*As the requirement for "product code" is that it does not contain letters, special characters or blank spaces
create the function val_code to go through each character entered in the code, check character by character with the isdigit function
to see if the character is numeric or not, if it is not numeric it prints a warning message and allows the user to try again
without leaving the console.*/

int val_code(char hello[]) {
    int abc;

    for (abc = 0; abc < strlen(hello); abc++) {

        if (!(isdigit(hello[abc]))) {

            cout << "The data entered is incorrect, try again ...";
            cout << endl;
            return 0;
        }

    }

    return 1;
}

void table()
{
    int c = k, m = 7;
    system("cls");
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Table of created products";
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << " number of order ";
    cout << "|     Name of product      |";
    cout << "   Product code    |";
    cout << "  Amount  |";
    cout << "   Unit price   |";
    cout << " Subtotal |";
    cout << "    IVA    |";
    cout << " total price |";
    cout << endl;
    cout << "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------";
    cout << endl;
    for (int L = 2; L <= c; L++)
    {
        cout << "                 ";
        cout << "|                          |";
        cout << "                   |";
        cout << "          |";
        cout << "                |";
        cout << "          |";
        cout << "           |";
        cout << "             |";
        cout << endl;
        cout << "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------";
        cout << endl;

    }

    for (int h = 1; h < c; h++)
    {

        gotoxy(8, m);
        cout << product[h].numor;
        gotoxy(20, m);
        cout << product[h].descr;
        gotoxy(52, m);
        cout << product[h].cod;
        gotoxy(70, m);
        cout << product[h].cant;
        gotoxy(83, m);
        cout << "$" << product[h].preuni;
        gotoxy(96, m);
        cout << "$" << product[h].subt;
        gotoxy(107, m);
        cout << "$" << product[h].IVA;
        gotoxy(119, m);
        cout << "$" << product[h].total;
        m = m + 4;
    }
    cout << "\n\n\n";
    system("pause");
    system("cls");
}
void gotoxy(int x, int y)
{
    HANDLE hcon;
    hcon = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    COORD dwPos;
    dwPos.X = x;
    dwPos.Y = y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hcon, dwPos);
}
```

Thank you very much in advance :)

Comment: Why are you jumping 4 lines here: `m = m + 4;`?

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Please don't post images of text. Post the [properly formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) instead.

Comment: Please post the results, in text, of your debugging session.  Which statement is causing the issue?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your program in a debugger yet?

Comment: @VladFeinstein is to skip line, print the next product in the next row of the table. If I don't put it, all the products will be printed in the same row

Comment: @ThomasMatthews When I enter the product table for the first time, the gotoxy prints it to me fine, but if I go back to the menu and enter the table again, the gotoxy skips a row. For example: if the first product was in the first row and the second product was in the second row, now I print the first product in the third row and the second product in the fifth row. (I don't know if I explained it well).
I want to assume that the problem is from the gotoxy but I have not been able to fix it ...

Comment: @jwdonahue I am doing it with Microsoft Visual Studio and it tells me that my code is fine, it does not detect any error

Comment: @grey, use `F9` to set a break point near the top of `main`, then hit `F5`, from there, `F10` step and `F11` to step-in (for drilling down into functions). At each step, note the state of your variables. Look for anything you wouldn't expect if the program is behaving correctly. While you may still have problems identifying the root cause, you should be able to narrow the problem down enough, that you can help us help you find the problem. The key is, if you demonstrate that you put in the effort, you're more likely to get more assistance.

Comment: As you get better at debugging, you'll solve more of your own issues on your own and you'll the job done quicker.

Comment: It would also help if you would [edit] your post to include input and output text. Nobody's going follow your image links, nor do we want to monkey test your program. Give us some inputs we can redirect into the program for testing. Otherwise, a repro for most of us just takes too much effort.

Comment: BTW, arrays in C++ are indexed from `0..Length - 1`, not `1..Length`. So `for (int h = 1; h < c; h++)` where it used to iterate through `products` has a bad smell.

Comment: It would also be easier to grok your code, if you serialized your display output. Rather than printing a grid on the screen, and then going back and filling the element values, write one loop that calls a print function for each of the kinds of row data (horizontal grid lines, data and vertical grid elements) you need to write. So you need at least two additional functions, and the one for the data and vertical grid elements can be a simple `printf` statement.

Comment: @grey Re: `is to skip line` - I understand that, but you are skipping FOUR lines, is that your intent?

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for this problem is that after the size of the console changes, the position of the symbols you draw has also changed. At the same time, the line break determined by `cout<<endl;` also has a problem. For example, after the window becomes larger, the line length of the console becomes larger, but `cout<<endl;` is still the original line length.

However, there is no good solution. I suggest you directly set the console size and `m=5, m=m+2`.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string>
#include<ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <windows.h>  
#include<iomanip>

using namespace std;

struct products
{
    int numor{},
        cant{};
    float preuni{},
        subt{},
        IVA{},
        total{};
    string cod{};
    string descr{};
}product[51];

void add();
void intro_code();
int val_code(char codigo[]);
void table();
void gotoxy(int x, int y);

int i = 1;                //Product No. (counter)
int k = 1;  //Consecutive number (counter)


int main()
{
    HWND console = GetConsoleWindow();
    RECT r;
    GetWindowRect(console, &r);
    MoveWindow(console, r.left, r.top, 1400, 400, TRUE);
    char opc;

    cout << "                Welcome ";
    cout << endl;


    cout << "\n1.- Add product.";
    cout << "\n2.- Delete product.";
    cout << "\n3.- Table of created products.";
    cout << "\n4.- Exit";
    cout << endl;
    cout << "\nWhat do you want to do today?: "; cin >> opc;




    switch (opc)
    {
    case '1':
        system("cls");
        cout << "\nAdd product";
        add();
        system("pause");
        system("cls");
        return main();
    case '2':
        cout << "\nDelete product";
        system("cls");
        return main();
    case '3':
        table();
        return main();
    case '4':
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    default:
        system("cls");
        cout << "Warning: the data entered is not correct, try again.\n\n";
        return main();
    }
    return 0;
}

void add()
{
    int can;

    cout << "\nHow many products do you want to register?: "; cin >> can;

    if (can <= 0 || can > 51)
    {
        system("cls");
        cout << "Warning: The amount of products entered is not valid, try again";
        return add();


    }

    for (int p = 1; p <= can;)
    {
        if (i < 51)
        {
            if (k <= 51)        // In this part, consecutive numbers are generated automatically
            {
                cout << "\nNumber of order: ";
                cout << k;
                cout << endl;
                product[i].numor = k;
                k++;
            }
            cin.ignore();
            cout << "Name of product: ";
            getline(cin, product[i].descr);
            intro_code();
            cout << "Quantity to sell: "; cin >> product[i].cant;
            cout << "unit price: $"; cin >> product[i].preuni;
            product[i].subt = product[i].preuni * product[i].cant;
            cout << "Subtotal: $" << product[i].subt;
            product[i].IVA = product[i].subt * 0.16;
            cout << "\nIVA: $" << product[i].IVA;
            product[i].total = product[i].subt + product[i].IVA;
            cout << "\nTotal price: $" << product[i].total;
            cout << "\n-------------------------------------------------------------------------------";
            cout << endl;
            i++;
        }
        p++;
    }
}
/*In this function the product code is entered, if the user enters a code
less than or greater than 5 characters the program displays an error message and allows the
user try again.*/
void intro_code()
{
    char hello[10];
    int xyz;
    do {
        cout << "Code of product (5 digits): ";
        cin.getline(hello, 10, '\n');
        if (strlen(hello) != 5)
        {
            cout << "The data entered is incorrect, try again ...";
            cout << endl;
            return intro_code();
        }
        else
        {
            xyz = val_code(hello);
        }
    } while (xyz == 0);
    product[i].cod = hello;
}
/*As the requirement for "product code" is that it does not contain letters, special characters or blank spaces
create the function val_code to go through each character entered in the code, check character by character with the isdigit function
to see if the character is numeric or not, if it is not numeric it prints a warning message and allows the user to try again
without leaving the console.*/

int val_code(char hello[]) {
    int abc;

    for (abc = 0; abc < strlen(hello); abc++) {

        if (!(isdigit(hello[abc]))) {

            cout << "The data entered is incorrect, try again ...";
            cout << endl;
            return 0;
        }

    }

    return 1;
}

void table()
{
    int c = k, m = 5;
    system("cls");
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Table of created products";
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << " number of order ";
    cout << "|     Name of product      |";
    cout << "   Product code    |";
    cout << "  Amount  |";
    cout << "   Unit price   |";
    cout << " Subtotal |";
    cout << "    IVA    |";
    cout << " total price |";
    cout << endl;
    cout << "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------";
    cout << endl;
    for (int L = 2; L <= c; L++)
    {
        cout << "                 ";
        cout << "|                          |";
        cout << "                   |";
        cout << "          |";
        cout << "                |";
        cout << "          |";
        cout << "           |";
        cout << "             |";
        cout << endl;
        cout << "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------";
        cout << endl;

    }

    for (int h = 1; h < c; h++)
    {

        gotoxy(8, m);
        cout << product[h].numor;
        gotoxy(20, m);
        cout << product[h].descr;
        gotoxy(52, m);
        cout << product[h].cod;
        gotoxy(70, m);
        cout << product[h].cant;
        gotoxy(83, m);
        cout << "$" << product[h].preuni;
        gotoxy(96, m);
        cout << "$" << product[h].subt;
        gotoxy(107, m);
        cout << "$" << product[h].IVA;
        gotoxy(119, m);
        cout << "$" << product[h].total;
        m = m + 2;
    }
    cout << "\n\n\n";
    system("pause");
    system("cls");
}
void gotoxy(int x, int y)
{
    HANDLE hcon;
    hcon = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    COORD dwPos;
    dwPos.X = x;
    dwPos.Y = y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hcon, dwPos);
}
```

In addition, it is not recommended that you use cmd to make gui.

Comment: @grey Have you got any updates? If your case has been solved, please help to mark answers. If not, just feel free to contact us.